# Why do these two queries produce different results?

Tags: sql, t-sql, null

I am trying to find the number of persons that are not in the application table.

I have two tables (*person and application*) with person having a one-to-many relationship with application (*person.id=application.person*).  However, a person may not have an application.  There are roughly 35K records in the application table.  I was able to reduce the query for the sake of this post and still produce the problem.  I would expect the first query to produce the same number of results as the second, but it does not.

Why does this query produce zero results:

```
select count(*) 
from person p where (p.id not in (
    select person
    from application 
))
```

While this query produces expected results:

```
select count(*) 
from person p where (p.id not in (
    select person
    from application 
    where person=p.id 
))
```

From my understanding, the second query is correct because:

1. when person has no app, inner select returns null in which `p.id not in null` returns true
2. when person has app, inner select returns app p.id in which `app
   p.id not in p.id` returns false

However, I do not understand why the first query does not equal the second.

Can someone please explain (thanks much)?

Comment: Based off of @gordon-linoff 's response, I found nulls in the subquery of the first query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `not in` with a subquery.  It does not treat `NULL` values correctly (or at least intuitively).  Instead, phrase the query as `not exists`:

```
select count(*) 
from person p
where not exists (select 1
                  from application a
                  where a.person = p.id 
                 );
```

With `NOT IN`, if *any* row in the subquery returns `NULL`, then no rows are returned at all to the outer query.

Your version with the correlation clause limits the damage.  However, my recommendation is to simply use `NOT EXISTS`.